# jQuery Function placement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I recently started learning jQuery, but I'm having trouble with a little animation program I got off of the jQuery website.
So here is the problem. This program works:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jQuery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<STYLE type="text/css">

#content {
    background-color:#6688ff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:3px;
    margin-top:5px;
    left: 100px;
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<input type="button" id="left" value="Left"/>
<input type="button" id="right" value="Right"/>
<div id="content">Move</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate(
            {"left": "+=50px"},
            "slow");
});
$("#left").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate(
                {"left": "-=50px"},
            "slow");
});
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But this program doesn't:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jQuery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate(
            {"left": "+=50px"},
            "slow");
});
$("#left").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate(
                {"left": "-=50px"},
            "slow");
});
</script>

<STYLE type="text/css">

#content {
    background-color:#6688ff;
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:3px;
    margin-top:5px;
    left: 100px;
}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<input type="button" id="left" value="Left"/>
<input type="button" id="right" value="Right"/>
<div id="content">Move</div>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The only difference between the two programs is where I put the javscript, so could anyone explain me why that makes a difference? Thanks, cause that is confusing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document isn't ready when the second jQuery code chunk runs, so it doesn't work.

*Always* wrap your jQuery code in a `$(document).ready()` statement:

```
$(document).ready() {
  $("#right").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
  });

  $("#left").click(function() {
    $("#content").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
  });
});
```

Your second code chunk is correct.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Why not? It lets the browser get on with rendering the actual page without having to parse the script first. Script in head with document.ready (or onload) and script at the end of the body are the two most common ways of doing it aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

The browser load/parse/render html and javascript from top to bottom, the one doesn't work as you put it before those html elements and when it runs it can't found those html tags, use jQuery ready can avoid this: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

the css should come before any javascript so that the document has all the elements preloaded.

Comment: i mean that the css should appear higher up in the DOM before js

Comment: It didn't matter if the css is after the JS, it matters if the html elements are.

Answer (score 0):

The second code block refers to `#right` before `right` is even declared.